# Why the thread is the same with multiple threads in PyCUDA

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I have the following program

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

mod = SourceModule("""
    #include <stdio.h>

     __global__ void myfirst_kernel()
       {
        printf("I am in block no: %d thread no: %d \\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
      }
""")
 
function = mod.get_function("myfirst_kernel")
function(grid=(10,2),block=(1,1,1))
```

As you can see I am running 10 blocks and 2 threads per block.
However the output is

```
python thread_execution.py 
I am in block no: 1 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 7 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 1 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 7 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 3 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 0 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 3 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 6 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 9 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 0 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 9 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 6 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 5 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 2 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 5 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 8 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 4 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 2 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 8 thread no: 0 
I am in block no: 4 thread no: 0
```

I was expecting threadIdx.x would give me 1 too. Why is always 0?

Comment: You are running one thread per block. Numbered from zero….

Answer (score 1):

You are not running multiple threads per block. This:

```
function(grid=(10,2),block=(1,1,1))
```

launches a grid of 10 x 2 blocks, each of one thread each. `threadIdx.x` will be zero in each case, with `blockIdx.x` varying between 0 and 9 (as shown in your output), and `blockIdx.y` varying between 0 and 1 (not shown in your output but the reason there are two outputs per value of `blockIdx.x`).